JMeter not uploading files to ASP .NET Application [Telerik web ui raU]
While creating JMeter script for an application I am not able to upload file using jmeter default file upload utility it says
{ "message" : "RadAsyncUpload handler is registered succesfully, however, it may not be accessed directly." }
When I modify my request like this
enter image description here
Somehow I managed to get the meta data and encrypted json response which I am sending in the subsequent request [Everything works fine till now], but upon completion when I go manually check the stuff the image is corrupted. There must be something with my request I am sure, but I am not able to figure it out.
I tried converting the image to base64, hexa, string etc but not working. Did anyone experience this issue or is there any other work around for upload files to Telerik RAD rau async file upload service

I think that instead of putting everything to "Body Data" tab you should rather use "Files Upload" tab of the HTTP Request sampler:

just make sure to copy the image to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and rename it to blob
Also if you're uncertain regarding how to properly implement this or that scenario you can always record it using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, just make sure that the file you're going to upload is in JMeter's "bin" folder.
More information: A Guide to the JMeter File Upload/Download Feature

yes I tried this but I am getting this message when I upload using File upload tab { "message" : "RadAsyncUpload handler is registered succesfully, however, it may not be accessed directly." }
